# How to write a HTTPS web service Client in java?

Tags: java, ssl, https, webservice-client, self-signed

For writing a web service client over HTTPS in java, we need to do an initial SSL handshake. How do we do an initial SSL handshake , if the web service is using it's own Self Signed Certificate ?
I need help in knowing the brief steps to write a client.

Comment: Do you actually want to write the low-level protocol implementation of an HTTPS client? Or just make an HTTPS call using one of the popular client libraries available for (and even included in) Java.

Comment: I want to make an HTTPS call using Java included libraries. The point at which I need help is about the flow/steps that I should follow to make the connection successful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the certificate and add it to cacerts.  I think 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19830-01/819-4712/ablqw/index.html  should help you.